# How do I reproduce in Illustrator the typeface that the web browser is displaying?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I'm trying to figure out how to reproduce the exact typeface of a font being displayed on my web site in order to use it as a typeface for a logo in Adobe Illustrator.

The text is ***AJ Acevedo*** in the header of http://ajacevedo.com. Which appears to be an italic and bold version of 'Lucida Grande'. At least on a mac using Safari.

The problem is that a bold/italic version of 'Lucida Grande' does not exist.
A close comparison reveals that the browser is not falling back to the 'Lucida Sans Demibold Italic'.

Here is the css for the `.site-title`

```
.site-title {  
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Demibold Italic", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;  
    font-weight: bold;  
    font-style: italic;  
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

The question is:
How do I reproduce the typeface that the browser is displaying for `.site-title` in a native OS app like Illustrator?

**NOTE:** If you do not have 'Lucida Grande' installed, your browser will fall back to 'Lucida Sans Demibold Italic'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your browser is [applying faux-bold and faux-italic styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9451858/1832306) to your text. I can only make assumptions without testing it, but I'd guess that your broswer *is* using Lucida Grande yet it is skewing and fattening the glyphs since there is no bold or italic versions available.

If you want to produce a vector version of this faux bolded and italicized font, you can use a PDF printer to print the page and the text should be saved as outlines. I used Acrobat as a PDF printer.  My browser falls back to use Lucida Sans Demibold Italic, but for illustration purposes here is the resulting page outlines (printed from Chrome, viewed in Illustrator):

[image: Illustrator Screenshot]

You can grab your vector logo from there.

[image: AJ Acededo]

Comment: I agree. After some poking with developer tools, Chrome on my Mac is using Lucida Grande and applying a faux italics via CSS. It's not bold in any way, faux or otherwise.

Comment: The elephant in the room here is that you should not use a faux rendering of bold, italic or small capitals as the basis for a logo, or for anything.